# Help needed with Median If in Excel

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, median

I need to return a median of only a certain category on a spread sheet.  Example Below

```
Airline    5
Auto       20
Auto       3
Bike       12
Airline    12
Airline    39
```

ect.

How can I write a formula to only return a median value of the Airline Categories.  Similar to Average if, only for median.  I cannot re-arrange the values.  Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742547/conditional-median-in-ms-excel

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742547/conditional-median-in-ms-excel

Answer (score 26):

Assuming your categories are in cells A1:A6 and the corresponding values are in B1:B6, you might try typing the formula `=MEDIAN(IF($A$1:$A$6="Airline",$B$1:$B$6,""))` in another cell and then pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` tells Excel to treat the formula as an "array formula".  In this example, that means that the `IF` statement returns an array of 6 values (one of each of the cells in the range `$A$1:$A$6`) instead of a single value. The `MEDIAN` function then returns the median of these values. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx for a similar example using `AVERAGE` instead of `MEDIAN`.

Comment: Can you tell me what CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER does here? I get different values if I press this shortcut and if I don't. I'm trying to learn which value is correct

Comment: @Piotrek change for a short while the formula from MEDIAN to SUM and you will understand how it works. The shortcut shift+cntr+enter makes the IF work. If you do not press it then it calculates the formula for entire range.

Answer (score 3):

Make a third column that has values like:

=IF(A1="Airline",B1)

=IF(A2="Airline",B2)
etc

Then just perform a median on the new column.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Brian Camire's Answer:

Using `=MEDIAN(IF($A$1:$A$6="Airline",$B$1:$B$6,""))` with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` will include blank cells in the calculation. Blank cells will be evaluated as 0 which results in a lower median value. The same is true if using the average funtion. If you don't want to include blank cells in the calculation, use a nested if statement like so:

```
=MEDIAN(IF($A$1:$A$6="Airline",IF($B$1:$B$6<>"",$B$1:$B$6)))
```

Don't forget to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to treat the formula as an "array formula".

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be to find a way of pulling the numbers from the string and placing them in a column of just numbers the using the =MEDIAN() function giving the new number column as the range