# Problem with Copy Pasting Array Formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put a vba formula which helps me find the median for a range of cells if these values pertain to a paricular category.

Here is the sheet sample with data:

[image: Snip of the Data]

This is the code i want to put in Cell B2 and then be able to drag it down till B7:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(F2:F100=A2,G2:G100),"NA"))
```

I have tried innumerable ways but can't find its solution.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Mayank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help needed with Median If in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752724/help-needed-with-median-if-in-excel)

Comment: If you're using VBA, can you [edit] your question with the code you've tried?

Comment: your formula has too many `)` should be `=MEDIAN(IF(F2:F100=A2,G2:G100,"NA"))` but the `,"NA"` can also be removed. :`=MEDIAN(IF(F2:F100=A2,G2:G100))`

Comment: Where is the VBA in your post? Please show one or some of your *innumerable ways* you tried and specific issues (errors/undesired results) that occur.

Answer (score -1):

For Vba try FormulaArray property.

```
Sheet1.Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=MEDIAN(IF(I:I=A2,J:J))"
Sheet1.Range("B2").Copy
Sheet1.Range("B3:B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
```

[image]