# Ignoring DIV/0! errors when calculating MEDIAN

Tags: excel

This may or may not be quite a simple one for the excel community. I have some data I wish to calculate the `MEDIAN` value for, and I'm using something similar to:

```
=MEDIAN(A1:A100)
```

This however spits back the following error:

```
Error: Function DIVIDE parameter 2 cannot be zero.
```

Which I assume is caused by cells containing the `DIV/0!` error. How do I allow excel to skip over such values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional median in MS Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742547/conditional-median-in-ms-excel)

Comment: I'd also have a look [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/547289-getting-median-and-percentile-to-exclude-error-values.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A100),A1:A100))
```

[Reference](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/547289-getting-median-and-percentile-to-exclude-error-values.html)